# DB::listen get query type

Tags: laravel-5, php-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I am using the following code to listen to my DB changes in my whole app.

`/app/Providers/AppServiceProviders.php`:

```
<?php

/* ... */

public function boot()
{
    DB::listen(function( $query ) {
        // $query->sql
        // $query->bindings
        // $query->time
    });
}

/* .... */

?>
```

Check [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database#running-queries) (paragraph: *Listening For Query Events*) to go the the related documentation for `DB::listen`.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to get the query type (e.g. to know if it was an INSERT, a SELECT, an UPDATE or a DELETE) without having to overwhelm my code of `preg_match` on the raw sql string ?

**WHAT I WOULD SEE**

Maybe something like:

```
<?php
    DB::listen( function( $query ) {
        // ...
    }, 'update');
?>
```

or even better (able to bind multiples query types:

```
<?php
    DB::after('update insert delete', function( $query ) {
        // ...
    });
?>
```

Comment: What about model events see [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) !!

Comment: I checked on Model events but this does not feet my needs since I have to copy paste the same method for my 20 models. I would like to dispose of something flexible.